# jquery-validation-engine isOverflown and overflownDIV

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I think I need to use the "isOverflown" ( probably set as "true" ) and "overflownDIV" ( probably set to some DIV selector ).   These options are specified on this [blog post](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/).  Has anyone used these options?  I can see it in the source code, but I cannot get it to work.  I think I am setting "overflownDIV" to the wrong value.  Any examples would be much appreciated.

As per another post, I am trying to get the scrolling to work correctly and I believe these two options are meant to help with that.

EDIT:

I believe, based on the reference to isOverflown being deprecated, that overflownDIV is also deprecated.

Underneath the "demos" directory, there are a bunch of helpful examples.

One such example is for the "overflownDIV" situation ( demoOverflown.html ).  But I actually don't think it does anything.  I don't think it does anything because, in the code for the engine itself ( jquery.validationEngine.js ), and the debugger, it won't get to that part of the code unless "isOverflown" is true, and since isOverflown is false, we never get into that part of the code for the demo.  There is no reference to "isOverflown" at all under "demos".  In fact, the only reference is in jquery.validationEngine.js.  As such, it seems that that feature has been deprecated.  If anyone disagrees, please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that I found a post suggesting that maybe isOverflown has been deprecated, which may be why it is not doing what I think it should do.  The post is [here](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/issues/105)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to solve this type of issue can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119940/jquery-validation-engine-scroll-to-first-error/23160980#23160980), especially since isOverflown seems to have been deprecated.